# How can one run an SSRS report using a set of data which is defined prior to the report being opened?

Tags: reporting-services

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this question, but I can't find any good answers;

I have a .net application which has a facility for deleting persons (the central entity in the system). The user can filter the set of persons that can be deleted in various ways, after which persons matching filter criteria are displayed in a grid; the user can then select/deselect individual persons in this grid to be deleted;

After this, but before actually deleting the persons, we need to show a report of these persons, for audit purposes;

Thus while the report will print data from the persons table, we need to pass a pre-defined subset of persons existing in the persons table, into the report, so the report shows the correct subset of data.

The problem defined here is indicative only - being the first report of this type being tackled, but any number of system reports will need to be able to print a pre-defined data subset. Moreover as the system allows unlimited users, there is ample scope for multiple users to report the same data at the same time, and thus setting a flag on table rows to indicate which rows should be selected isnt a viable solution.

The only solution I can conceive of thus far, is to dynamically generate an sql statement to represent the data printed with a " AND Person.ID IN (list)" in the WHERE clause, and save that sql statement as a series of 8k chunks of text in a permanent table; Pass the ID of that table's row into a report via a url and make the report's data source a stored procedure, which uses the passed ID as a parameter: The stored procedure uses the ID to find the row in the table containing the sql needed to produce the report's data, and collates the sql using a bunch of varchar(8000) variables, executes the sql, and returns the required data to the report.

However this is rather ick... how can it be done more cleanly?

Comment: Is your app a web app, or a Winforms app?

Comment: Are your reports server reports or local reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create Report table that would have two columns PersonID and ReportID. Whenever the user selects a list of persons, you insert their ID's on this table and generate a new ReportID and on your report your query will need to do an Inner Join against this table.

(essentially the same that you described but less hacky)

and if besides the list of people you need other details (such as which fields to show) you can use the same approach.

Another alternative is, since you're using a .Net app you can pass all the personIDs to the parameter list (create a multi-value parameter on your report) and SSRS will be able to deal with it.

Comment: I like both your suggestions, and will have a go and see what I can achieve; I'm not accepting your answer yet, I'll see if anyone else comes up with any other ideas - but should mark something as an answer in the next 24 hours or so